# Is there any system that generates website designs?

Tags: research, open-source, artificial-creativity

I was thinking about what I can do for my thesis in upcoming academic semester, and I came across an idea. The idea is like: "If there is any kind of system that generates website designs itself." If no, then I can go for it, and I will be lucky if anyone has the same idea. We can collaborate. In case, if there's any project or system (Open source or not) that can do this or has been initiated in this context, I want to contribute solely. If anyone has any clue or knowledge over this kind of system, please do inform me. As I haven't done anything like this before, I want to learn. Any kind of suggestion or assistance on this idea will be so helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

The closest research that I am aware of is in artificial intelligence designed user interfaces([1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370210000822),[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07962)).

The scope of which vary tremendously. Some teams are trying to generate UIs based on some user-defined parameters, others are trying to generate based off of images(as in the second link). I think part of the reason research is focused here is two-fold: One, we aren't very good at generating UIs automatically yet, and 2, it is an exponentially harder problem to develop a backend that has integrated calls and features required for a fully-featured website or application.

With that being said, one could adapt this research into things like one-page sites or other simple implementations that might bear fruit.

Comment: i thought of this system like, it'll only design frontend and not backend. Will it be fruitful to spend my important time for it? What do you think? I'm seeking motivation actually and really want to implement a system like this.

Comment: I don't like recommending research paths, but if you have a significant interest in the problem I would say yes.

Comment: That's okay actually. I'd love to learn from you.

Comment: Cool, if you deem my answer acceptable, go ahead and check it. If you want, give me a way to correspond and I will do so